# multi module component scanning not working in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am having two module web and business. I have included business in the web. But when I try to include a service interface from business into web using `@autowired`, it is giving `org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException`.

So, basically `@SpringBootApplication` is not able to scan the `@Service` from business module.

Is it something simple, I am missing?

If I add `@Bean` for that service in the `@SpringBootApplication` class, it is working fine.

Code:

```
package com.manish;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootConfiguration {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootConfiguration.class, args);
    }
}
```

Class from module 1 from which is calling class from module 2:

```
package com.manish.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import uk.co.smithnews.pmp.service.contract.UserRegistrationService;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/testManish")
public class SampleController {

    @Autowired
    private SampleService sampleService;
....
}
```

Module 2:

```
package com.manish.service;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class SampleServiceImpl implements SampleService {
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: How do you build and run your application? Can you post your build configuration?

Comment: Thanks dunni, there was a type in my code, which was causing the issue. When I was trying to paste the code for you, I figured it out.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`@SpringBootApplication` only scans the packages of the class with the annotation itself and all packages below.

Example: If the class with the SpringBootApplication annotation is in the package `com.project.web`, then this packages and all below that are scanned.

However, if you have your services in the package `com.project.business`, the beans won't be scanned.

In that case you have to add the annotation `@ComponentScan()` to your application class, and add all packages you want to scan as value in that annotation, e.g. `@ComponentScan({"com.project.web", "com.project.business"})`.

Comment: my multi modules are having same base package and I have kept my configuration at the root of my base backage. So, it shouldn't be a concern.

Comment: Well, then you have to give more information about your project structure etc. The component scan doesn't care, if your classes are stored in different JARs, as long as they are on the classpath.

Comment: I have added my code but everything still seems quite straight forward. Thanks

Comment: you can also @ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.project"}) this will scan all packages  com.project.*

Comment: But other auto configuration classes from spring doesn’t start…