# maven cannot find symbol but IDEA can

Tags: maven

in maven module A:
`import com.mycompany.my.moduleB.FooService;`

FooService is in maven module B, 
`public interface FooService<T> {}`
module A pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-moduleB</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

When running module A main function, IDEA works fine, but maven gives `cannot find symbol com.mycompany.my.moduleB.FooService` even though moduleB success.

I have tried `maven -U`

Comment: Have you run `mvn clean install` on module B before doing the same with module A?

Comment: @gjoranv I have. Actually, I run the command in parent module, which run apply the command to every submodule including moduleA and B

Comment: Please ensure that both modules have the same value in the project/version element in the pom, and then I suggest to use `<version>${project.version}</version>` instead of `0.0.1-SNAPSHOT` in the dependency section above. If this doesn't help, I suggest to include both the pom files in the question, so it's perhaps easier to figure out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [multi module component scanning not working in spring boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33080261/multi-module-component-scanning-not-working-in-spring-boot)